# Node.js: can not install iconv module

Tags: node.js, installation, iconv

I try to install `iconv` module, but it always stay at:

```
^Cyippeeyippee@mini: server$ npm install iconv
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/iconv

> iconv@1.2.3 install /Users/yippeeyippee/Desktop/nodejs/tinman/server/node_modules/iconv
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp http GET http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.7/node-v0.8.7.tar.gz
gyp http 200 http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.8.7/node-v0.8.7.tar.gz
```

I don't know what happened,success or failed, how can I solve this problem?

**Update:**

After waiting a long time:, I got the failed information like this:

```
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app to select /Applications/Xcode.app, or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yippeeyippee/.node-gyp/0.8.7/tools/gyp/gyp", line 18, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "/Users/yippeeyippee/.node-gyp/0.8.7/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 480, in main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "/Users/yippeeyippee/.node-gyp/0.8.7/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2082, in GenerateOutput
    part_of_all=qualified_target in needed_targets)
  File "/Users/yippeeyippee/.node-gyp/0.8.7/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 764, in Write
    self.Pchify))
  File "/Users/yippeeyippee/.node-gyp/0.8.7/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 1137, in WriteSources
    cflags = self.xcode_settings.GetCflags(configname)
  File "/Users/yippeeyippee/.node-gyp/0.8.7/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 259, in GetCflags
    sdk_root = self._SdkPath()
  File "/Users/yippeeyippee/.node-gyp/0.8.7/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 248, in _SdkPath
    return os.path.join(self._GetSdkBaseDir(), '%s.sdk' % sdk_root)
  File "/Users/yippeeyippee/.node-gyp/0.8.7/tools/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 234, in _GetSdkBaseDir
    raise Exception('Error %d running xcode-select' % job.returncode)
Exception: Error 1 running xcode-select
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:346:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process._handle.onexit (child_process.js:674:10)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 11.4.0
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/yippeeyippee/Desktop/nodejs/tinman/server/node_modules/iconv
gyp ERR! node -v v0.8.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.6.8
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! iconv@1.2.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@1.2.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the iconv package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls iconv
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Darwin 11.4.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "iconv"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/yippeeyippee/Desktop/nodejs/tinman/server
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.49
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/yippeeyippee/Desktop/nodejs/tinman/server/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Have you properly installed node-gyp and its dependencies?  https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

Comment: @JohnnyHK: I have install it already v0.6.8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## The Command Line Tools Only (No Xcode) Method

1. Download and install the Mac OS X Developer [Command Line Tools](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#)
2. run `sudo xcode-select --switch /usr/bin`. See [homebrew issue 10245](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10245) for details
3. Retry your `npm install iconv`

## The Xcode Version (Untested by me)

1. Download and install full [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action#)
2. try your `npm install iconv` again. If it works, you're done.
3. If you get the same error, try `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app` then retry your `npm install iconv`

Comment: I had the "Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1" and running "sudo xcode-select -switch /usr/bin" did the job ! Thanx !!

Comment: Thanks! This solution seems to fix that node-gyp error for the npm pg package aswell (postgres)

Answer (score 0):

At this step node-gyp installer download node.js source code. This may take a long time and depending on your connection speed. For example: I waiting about 20-25 minutes at this step on server with very slow connection located in China.

Comment: Maybe it's not the problem, I have already update the failed information;

Comment: Are you using Mac OS? Try to see the same issue here https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/10245 . Executing "sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app" may help you. But i don't have  Mac OS to check this.