# Installation on nodej.js pg module issue (Cannot open include file: 'pg_config.h')

Tags: node.js, postgresql

While installing the pg module on Windows I can to this problem:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\pg>node "c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node
  -gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
  binding.cc
  ..\src\binding.cc(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'pg_config.h': No such file or directory [c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\
  node_modules\pg\build\binding.vcxproj]
  gyp ERR! build error
  gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:267:23)
  gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
  gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:789:12)
  gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
  gyp ERR! command "node" "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
  gyp ERR! cwd c:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\pg
  gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.24
  gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.1
  gyp ERR! not ok
  pg@2.11.1 node_modules\pg
  ├── nan@0.6.0
  ├── generic-pool@2.0.3
  ├── buffer-writer@1.0.0
  └── pgpass@0.0.1 (split@0.2.10)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue installing node-postgres with npm (on windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14487632/issue-installing-node-postgres-with-npm-on-windows)

Comment: Read the installation instructions for Windows. Make sure `pg_config` (the executable) is on the `PATH`. Make sure PostgreSQL is installed.

Answer (score 0):

My environment:

```
win - 8.1
vs - 2012
pg - 9.3
nodejs - 0.10.29
npm - 1.4.14
```

pg path `"D:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin"` has been manually added into the system env var "PATH".

I got the same error, and noticed the path in the `\pg\build\binding.vcxproj` file was `D:\Program;..\Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\include\;...`

so the space in the pg path could be the problem. After changed the pg install path, problem solved.